# Trouble retrieving information from a web page using HTTP protocol

Tags: python-3.x

This is my first question on this forum. So here we go.

In an assignment on coursera python for everybody, I modified the url in a .py  file as told to retrieve the document from the link provided. But after doing all and running in cmd, I get ‘socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed’ error. I also can’t get to work this with the other alternative methods i.e., browser developer console and telnet. Telnet throws a ‘Could not open connection to the host, on port 80: Connect failed’ error.

I looked into google but not getting a clear answer. It would really help if someone solved this issue for me.

```
import socket

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('http://data.pr4e.org/intro-short.txt', 80))
cmd = 'GET http://data.pr4e.org/intro-short.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()
mysock.send(cmd)

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if len(data) < 1:
        break
    print(data.decode(),end='')

mysock.close()
```

I expect to get the metadata and contents of the url.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Why not use `requests.get('http://data.pr4e.org/intro-short.txt')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sockets don't understand urls, only hostnames.  You need to change

```
mysock.connect(('http://data.pr4e.org/intro-short.txt', 80))
```

to

```
mysock.connect((data.pr4e.org', 80))
```